# Lambda Invocation User

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

i am trying to get a user who invokes a lambda function through the console using boto3.

Tried using cloud watch and Event bridge to get the user and passing it to the function.
Also tried getting the caller identity using STS. However, It returns the function role and function name as the user instead.